# Cannot get mask from pyganim

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame, PygAnimation
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = PygAnimation([("png/Attack__000.png",.08),   ("png/Attack__001.png",.08),("png/Attack__002.png",.08),
            ("png/Attack__003.png",.08),("png/Attack__004.png",.08),("png/Attack__005.png",.08),],True)
    def update(self):
        self.image.play()
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)

    def draw(self):
        self.image.blit(screen,(100,100)) 

p = Player()


running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.fill((255,255,255))

    p.draw()
    p.update()
    pygame.display.update()
```

I keep getting errors when trying to get the mask it says argument 1 must be pygame.surface not pyganimation.
I have tried many ways to get masks but all efforts have proved futile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the traceback says you have to pass a [`pygame.Surface`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) to [`pygame.mask.from_surface`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.from_surface), but the `self.image` is a `PygAnimation` object not a surface. You can get the current frame (which is a `pygame.Surface`) of the animation by calling `self.image.getCurrentFrame()`.

```
self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image.getCurrentFrame())
```

---

Also, the durations are in milliseconds, so change `.08` to something higher like `50`.

Comment: I think you can't use your Player sprite in a sprite group because its `self.image` attribute should be a `pygame.Surface`, so I'd store the animation as `self.animation` and then update the `self.image` of the sprite in the `update` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked fine

Comment: You're welcome. Please upvote and accept the answer, that will give you a few points as well.

Comment: Sorry, just came back to my account after a couple of years cause I forgot to upvote. Thanks!